# URL - Encoding (JavaScript) method="GET"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, urlencode

I have a form with some input fields (6). When I click the submit button "I would like to format the URL" in such a way:

```
/actionname?input1|input2|input3|input4|input5|input6
```

and maybe for null values:

```
/actionname?input1|input2||input4||input6
```

and maybe a time-stamp for when the user clicks the submit button.

Can this be done using javascript.

Thanks,

Chad

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You will use that as a separator and split it at the server?

Comment: yes...but instead of /actionname?input1=something1&input2=something2&input3=something3 

I  would like to have something along the lines of 
/actionsname?something1|something2|something3|something4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using any java script library like jQuery, you can serialize the form which gives the data in query string format. ex: [see here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)

Comment: That builds a query string like the one obtained by standard GET submit on the form. The OP wants to custom format the URL. serialize() won’t do that.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via javascript but I can't understand why you would want to.  You would have to use the onsubmit event of the form, loop through the form elements appending each value to a url string in the format you offered and then setting `window.location` to that url string.

For users with javascript disabled, the form would still submit in the "proper" manner, which is why I can't understand why you would want to change the format of the query string.

Comment: I have a stored proc ready to parse values from  the url "/actionname?" 
This call will insert values into tables. for me using "|" can easily be parsed by my web service

Answer (score 0):

Even if I do not see any reason why you would need this :), you can use the [onSubmit](http://www.ehow.com/how_2056355_use-onsubmit-javascript.html) event to create the proper url and redirect to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use the [XMLHTMLRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to perform your request.

You construct your URL in a string using javascript and then set-up the XHR to submit to that URL using a GET (synchronously or a synchronously, your choice).

This way you also avoid stepping on the toes of the `onsubmit` form event.

Alternatively, a simple workaround will be to construct your URL in a string and then set the form `action` attribute to this string before submitting the form with the `submit(`) method.